# How can I insert multiple variables in an api link in my python code

Tags: python, api, python-requests, openweathermap

I am making a weather app and instead of having someone enter their coordinates, I have it where when they enter their city it will pull the coordinates of the city from an API. I then have the lat and lon values that were just pulled stored in two different variables. So what I want to do is be able to insert those lat and lon variables into another API link then make the request for the weather data.

```py
import requests
import math
from datetime import datetime
import tzlocal

api_address1 = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=fAPI KEY='

city = input("City Name :")

url1 = api_address1 + city

json_data1 = requests.get(url1).json()

lat = json_data1['coord']['lat']
lon = json_data1['coord']['lon']

print (lat, lon)

api_address2 = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?{}=&{}=&appid=API KEY'

sun_rise = json_data1['sys']['sunrise']

local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone()
local_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(sun_rise, local_timezone)

print(local_time.strftime("%B %d %Y %H:%M" + "AM"))de here
```

Comment: that sound like ... very basic string formatting, could use `f strings`: `f"{variable}string"`

Answer (score 0):

In such cases you should use [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

In your example it would work like this:

```
api_address2 = f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid=API KEY'
```